# How to specify a twig template for a custom Drupal 8 page?

Tags: theming, routes

I'm trying to create a custom Drupal 8 route with predefined content, like `/about-us`, which is not a node, just a standalone page.

The following tutorial is good only up to the point where I need to add the page content using `#markup`: https://www.drupal.org/node/2116767

How can I specify a twig template that I would like to use for page content?

Answer (score 9):

I got that to work. Here's my solution.

Create a template in `path/to/your/module/templates/my-custom-page.html.twig`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    return [
        'my_custom_page' => [
            'render element' => 'custom_page',
            'path' => $path . '/templates',
            'template' => 'my-custom-page',
            'variables' => [
                'var1' => 'default value for var1',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I couldn't figure out what `render element` is for, but it is required.

`variables` element defines the variables available in your template and provides default values for them. You can override them in your controller.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Class CustomPageController
 */
class CustomPageController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function getPage()
    {
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'my_custom_page',
            '#var1' => 'Actual value for var1',
        );
    }

}
```

Clear the cache and visit your custom page route. Everything should work.

Helpful links:

- [Render API
  overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8)
- [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8)